# Integro-Differential Equation in von Neumann Equation

Tags: differential-equations, integral-equations

I'm trying to implement the von Neumann Equation for a 2x2 density Matrix with a time dependent Hamiltonian H0[t] with exponential dissipation in Mathematica

\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{\rho}=-i[H_{0}(t),\rho(t)]-A^{2}\Big[H_{1},\int_{t1}^{t}e^{-B(t-s)}\Big(e^{-i\int_{s}^{t}H_{0}(t')dt'}\Big)[H_{1},\rho(s)]\Big(e^{i\int_{s}^{t}H_{0}(t')dt'}\Big)ds\Big] 
\end{eqnarray}

```
L=100;

X=1;

v=0.5;

h1=-10;

h2=10;

t1=h1/v;

t2=h2/v;

A=2;

B=0.1;


For[m = 1, m <= L/2, m = m + 1,


k=((2m-1)*\Pi)/L;


H0[t_]= 2*{{v*t - J*Cos[k],  -I*x*Sin[k]},
           {I*x*Sin[k],      -v*t + J*Cos[k]}};

H1=2*{{1,0},{0,-1}} + 2*x*Sin[k]*{{0,-I},{I,0}};

rhoini ={{1, 0},{0, 0}};

    NDSolveValue[{rho'[t] == -I*(H0[t].rho[t] - rho[t].H0[t])

                          - A^2*(H1.(NIntegrate[E^(-B*(t - s))*

                          MatrixExp[-I*NIntegrate[H0[t'], {t', s,t}]]. 

                         (H1.rho[s] - rho[s].H1).

                         MatrixExp[I*NIntegrate[H0[t'], {t', s, t}]], 

                         {s, t1, t}]))

                         + A^2*((NIntegrate[E^(-B*(t - s))*

                         MatrixExp[-I*NIntegrate[H0[t'], {t', s,t}]]. 

                        (H1.rho[s] - rho[s].H1).     
       
                        MatrixExp[I*NIntegrate[H0[t'], {t', s, t}]],

                        {s, t1, t}]).H1), rho[t1] == rhoini}, rho], 

                        {t, t1, t2}];

Print[rho[t2][[1, 1]]]

];
```

All elements of matrices H0[t], H1[t] and all parameters A, B are known.
I was wondering if you would be able to help me.
Thank you

Comment: Please provide code defining H0[t], H1[t] and A, B in the question.  Without that information, readers cannot offer much assistance.

Comment: First, please provide the full code, and second, the above code consists of some minor issues, such as `e` should be `Exp` or `E`.

Comment: This is not answerable bases on the information provided. I'm voting to close this question until the question is [edit]ed to add enough detail and context.